# Cyrillic data in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, character-encoding

Everything was working fine while the database of my asp.net mvc 2 site was in the app_data folder, after I transfered it to sqlserver express all the Cyrillic data I added after that appears in ?????

I'm using nvarchar for my fields and collation is set to Cyrillic and yet I get `?????`...

Any suggestions are appreciated

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddCity(CityInfo cityInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var dbM = new moonDB2();

                    dbM.CityInfoes.AddObject(cityInfo);
                    dbM.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {

                    return View(cityInfo);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using nvarchar for my fields and
>   encoding is set to Cyrillic

Irrelevant. NVarchar is unicode - so the encoding is not relevant. Encoding is relevant for varchar (coding page) only.

- Validate it is the database, not the asp.net area
- Are you ENCODING the letters in ASP.NET? What is your server side asp.net locale?

I am more likely to believe you f***** up the string handing in the ASP.NET side, or run thecode somewhere through a CHAR / VARCHAR columns. NVARCHAR handles cyrillic fine.

Comment: i'm using EF to insert the data directly into the DB see code provided

Comment: Even more irrelevant. Collation is sort order. Even if you put it to japanese it has to store the nvarchar properly.. I suggest you throw out EF and make a TEST (SIMPLE) without EF. Strip an insert down to the minimum and validate the behvavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `EntityDataModel` `string` property's `Unicode` Facet to `true`.